# Checking whether the function $g(x)=6-2x-x^2$ is either one-one or onto

Tags: functions

If $A=[-4,\infty),B=(-\infty,8]$ and $g:A\to B$ is defined by $g(x)=6-2x-x^2$  for every $x$ in $A$, then check whether $g$ is  either one to one or onto.

Here $g(0)=6=g(-2)$ so $g$ is onto one-to-one but show $g$ is either onto or not

Comment: Did you mean to say that $g$ is not one-to-one?

Answer (score 1):

$y= -(x+1)^2 +7;$

1)Maximum of this function is $7$ at $x=-1$.

Not surjective.

2)$y(-2) = -1 +7=6$; $y(0) = -1+7 =6.$

Not injective .

Note: This is a parabola with vertex $(-1,7)$ opening downward.

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is neither one-one nor onto since $6 - 2x - x^2 = 8$ has no solutions in $A,$ and like you mentioned, $g(0) = g(-2).$